# Help with typedef enum

Tags: iphone, objective-c, enums, sdk, typedef

This is my first time using a typedef enum and I need some help setting it. Here is some of my code:

```
typedef enum {
user,
vip,
admin
} status;
@property (nonatomic, assign) status status;
```

When I call this

```
[self setStatus:vip];
```

It works fine. But when I call it again, the app crashes with nothing in the console. I call it again, but with a different status, such as

```
[self setStatus:user];
```

What should I do to fix my code? Thanks in advance

Also, status is synthesized in the .m.

Comment: Have you tried setting it to 'user' first, and then to 'vip'? Does it behave the same way in this case?

Comment: @Ken Wayne VanderLinde Yes, it has the same effect

Comment: Have you declared a backing instance variable? It’d be helpful if you posted your class declaration.

Comment: Also let me add that in the view did load, I set it to none (forgot to add that to the example in the OP) and it works when it is set to vip/user the first time but not the second time changing it.

Comment: @Bavarious do you mean adding NSString *_status; and setting it equal to the typedef?

Comment: Well, not an `NSString *` since an enum type is realised as an integer type. If you have a backing instance variable, it should have the same type as the corresponding declared property, namely your enum.

Comment: sounds like he didn't have an instance variable of the typedef

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of nonatomic & assign... make it readwrite since typedef is technically represented by numbers.

Comment: Declared properties have the `readwrite` attribute by default.

Comment: Perhaps you could try to override the setter methods and see if you can recreate the problem with your own method?

Answer (score 1):

try this code instead

```
typedef enum {
    user,
    vip,
    admin
} Status

@implementation thisClass {
    Status status;
}

@property (nonatomic, readwrite) Status status;
```

Comment: Declared properties have the `readwrite` attribute by default.

Comment: As for your last edit, there is no problem in having a type with the same name as a declared property/variable since they’re in separate namespaces.

Comment: well, guess ill delete all this since its obviously useless